# query error when access clearDB database using php on Heroku

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, cleardb

I can access clearDB database well by using Mysql Workbench.

But when I query database by using php on Heroku, it always fail.

This is my code:

```
$url=parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));

$dbhost = $url["host"];
$dbuser = $url["user"];
$dbpass = $url["pass"];
$dbname = substr($url["path"],1);

mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

mysqli_select_db($dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user_info` WHERE `user_account`='".$user_account."'";

$result = mysqli_query($sql) or die('MySQL query error');
```

user_account is a table in the database, $user_account is a input variable from client user

help me 
thanks

Comment: Is `user_account` a table or a field in the table `user_info`? And add an error message if you're receiving one.

Comment: user_account is a field in table user_info. And I just receive 'MySQL query error'

Comment: dzuelke solve my problem. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the link to `mysqli_query()`. You need to either do that, or use the object oriented style and call `query()` on the connection.

You also have a possible SQL injection there, because `$user_account` could contain "`foo' OR 1 OR '`", returning all rows (and that's just a simple, not very evil case), so you should escape that using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, or even better, use prepared statements.

Finally, instead of `or die()`, how about extracting error information properly, or even configuring mysqli to throw exceptions?

```
<?php
$url = parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));

$server = $url["host"];
$username = $url["user"];
$password = $url["pass"];
$db = substr($url["path"], 1);

$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $db);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user_info` WHERE `user_account`='".$conn->real_escape_string($user_account)."'";

if($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    foreach($result as $row) {
        // ...
    }
} else {
    throw new Exception($conn->error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you solving my problem.